# Laravel phpspec cannot be autoloaded

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpspec

I am trying to setup phpspec in a Laravel project.

I have installed phpspec properly and am running phpspec inside my project without any trouble.

My composer.json file has the following relevant lines:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Acme\\": "app/Acme"
    }
},
```

My phpspec.yml:

```
suites:
  app_suite:
    namespace: Acme
    src_path: app
    spec_path: app
    spec_prefix: spec
```

Executing `phpspec describe Acme/Foo` created `app\spec\Acme\FooSpec.php` file.
Executing `phpspec run` created `app\Acme\Foo.php`

But I am getting the following error when I run "phpspec run" -

> The type Acme\Foo was generated but could not be loaded. Do you need
>   to configure an autoloader?

Everything is fine, except for the auto-loading error. How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
composer dump-autoload
```

It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included, when you have a new class inside your project

Comment: The default locations used by phpspec for the spec files and source files are `spec` and `src` respectively. If you don't have the namespace parameter in the phpspec.yml then place your files in the default location.